Trouble retrieving geojson from ESRI Rest service
I'm trying to get a geojson from this ESRI REST server and plug it into a QGIS map. I'm looking only for points where RptYear=2024.
I've gone through the basic steps in QGIS of clicking on "ArcGIS REST Servers," adding the url, and clicking OK, but no data or geojson is coming back and I keep getting 'Connectin failed: Network error'.
When I use that same url on geodatadownloader.com it works just fine and I can download the geojson, but in the resulting file the date and time field—which I really need—is all messed up. They come back as long numbers that don't correspond in any way I can figure out to the actual date and time. You can see the ESRI map here with the proper "offense_dttm" field here.
Any guidance on how to add this data to QGIS through the built-in function, or to figure out what's going with the file coming back from geodatadownloader would be much appreciated!

Open qgis application
and go to  layer tab >>add arcgis rest server layer>> new > in the connection details give any name for name filed in your case 'shooting v2' in the url give the below one
enter link description here
In the shootingV2 drop down you will get shooting layer select and add.
After that right click on the layer and
Select filter and enter "RptYear" = 2024
And click on ok
